# Table types with dba objects

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

Why can't we create an object with the below code.

```
create or replace type typ_obj_dba_test as object (name_col 
                  dba_objects.object_name%type);
```

It gives me object_name must be declared.

Is it because dba_objects is a view?

Answer (score 1):

> "Is it because dba_objects is a view?"

No. You couldn't do it with a table column either. The `%TYPE` syntax is restricted to PL/SQL and you are creating a SQL TYPE, not PL/SQL.

This restriction is annoying to many developers, particularly those coming from a background in more dynamic programming languages. But the snag is `%TYPE` syntax  *is* dynamic: if the referenced column changes its data type the referencing object changes.

That's neat when we're declaring variables or parameters in stored procedures. But we can use SQL types to define table columns **(*)**. Cascading a change in one column to who-knows-how-many columns which reference it would be a nightmare. So Oracle doesn't allow us to do it.

I'm afraid you'll need to use an explicit datatype declaration:

```
create or replace type typ_obj_dba_test as object (
   name_col varchar2(30)
 );
```

**(*)** It's not generally advisable to use Types in table definitions, but Oracle supports ORDBMS data structures.